# Radon Fan Getting Noisy & Other Questions

Tags: drain, fans, sump-pump, radon

We are wrapping up a French drain installation, and our radon fan has been much noisier for the last day or so. The concrete has been poured over our new French drain piping, with the sump pump hole still open. The rest of the project will be finished in a few days. Radon reading has decreased from 2.25 a few days ago down to 1.5. Next to Radon reading, I saw a label that suggested retesting radon after major alterations to the building. System looks quite new. We moved in less than a year ago, and the fan has never been this noisy.

I’ve seen videos of noisy radon fans, and our’s is not as loud as the examples I’ve seen. Tried to attach a video of our own noise but was unable to.

Should also note that there was water bubbling in the radon pipe earlier this week. This would happen following heavy rain. We’ve read that the French drain should help with this.

QUESTIONS:

1. Is the sudden increase in noise related more to our sump pump hole still being open, and should improved once it’s sealed?
2. Based on label, should I have radon retested? Not sure if this type of job is enough to be a major alteration to the building.
3. Could this issue simply be a new fan is already required?

With our French drain project wrapping up and a tile project starting soon, trying to avoid any unnecessary expenses. Either way, going to wait it out until we’re finished.

Appreciate any insight! New homeowner trying to stay on top of things and do it right.

Comment: Is the weather outside where you are below freezing? Ice falling down the exhaust pipe can make radon fans *quite* noisy. Ice forms in the vent pipes as moist warmer air from below ground hits the colder above-ground pipe, condenses and freezes. It may then dislodge from the pipe wall in a warmer spell and fall down to the fan. As you appear to have a monitor I would not worry about retesting until all your work is over with. Oh. No. You're looking at the suction on the pipe, not the actual radon level, aren't you? In that case I'd suggest getting a monitor...

Comment: When opening the hatch for the radon pipe in the wall, there’s a meter resembling a thermometer with red liquid that gives me a reading. Assuming this was to monitor radon levels.

Comment: No, that's to measure the suction being produced by the fan. It's lower because the sump is open, presumably, so there's a big leak at the top of the sump. Roughly speaking, a higher number is "better" at that gauge, as it means there's more suction on the radon pipes to remove radon. A radon monitor (used to cost 11K$ or so) can now be had for $100-200 and will tell you in real time what your radon levels are, and you can *keep it honest* with an occasional lab test.

Comment: Two new questions: 1. I see it’s easy to buy a portable radon meter. Is there any certain place it should be located? 2. Would the suction measurement have anything to do with fan noise?

Comment: Also, appreciate the advice!

Comment: The  lowest inhabited level, normally, but they are portable and read within 10 minutes to 24 hours (depending which you get) so you can move it around to see how it varies in the house. After the novelty wears off, either the lowest inhabited level or the basement if not inhabited but the system is pulling it below alarm levels, normally. The noise might or might not be due to the open sump making it move more air and produce less suction. Close the sump and you'll know.

Comment: Thanks again! Will try to provide an update once we’re done.